# Comma or semicolon?

Tags: punctuation

Do I use a comma or semicolon in the example below?

> For your convenience; changes are in red and I’ve also attached your prior comments.

Comment: Folks are expected to do some research before asking a question on the Stack Exchange. In this case, one can type `when to use a semicolon` into Google and get several pages of information that would answer this question, like [this one](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/semicolon/). I suggest that you look through our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for more helpful information. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 5):

Use a comma.

> For your convenience, changes are in red and I’ve also attached your prior comments.

The use of semicolons in English is extremely rare. When a semicolon is used, it is typically between two main clauses to indicate a pause that is more pronounced than that indicated by a comma.

In this case, "For your convenience," is not a main clause so a semicolon would not be appropriate.

Comment: The easy way to tell if it's a "main clause" is to try replacing the comma/semicolon with a period to make two separate sentences.  If each could stand alone as a sentence, the semicolon should be used instead of a comma.  "For your convenience" has no verb, and therefore could not be a sentence.

The second use of semicolons is to indicate a higher level of grouping:  "red, green, and blue; circle, triangle, and square".

Answer (score 0):

> For your convenience; changes are in red and I’ve also attached your prior comments.

edit:

> For your convenience, I have put changes in red and attached your prior comments.

or:

> I have put changes in red and attached your prior comments for your convenience.

It depends on where you wish to place an emphasis. The first is more interlocutor focused.
[I would probably say: previous comments]

Generally, pre-positioned adverbial phrases take a comma.